# jqgrid filterToolbar with spring mvc 3

Tags: spring-mvc, jqgrid

Greetings all,

Are there any examples for using 'filtertoolbar' with spring mvc 3 ? for my understanding is we need to post a request to the every letter user typed in the text box to the server side and filter the specific column accordingly. is this the right approach to do it? i am using json object that binds with response ('@ResponseBody'). can someone please give me some directions.. one another question is we need to arrange the dataset (json) according to the parameters user sent from the backend and will it be rendered as it is in the jqgrid? if i use .trigger("reloadGrid") ? Thanks in advance for your great help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) method together with the parameter `stringResult: true`. In the case the [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) will work exactly like [advance searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching) and in the parameter [filters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options) will be sent JSON encoded filter parameters. If you will use another parameter `searchOnEnter:true`, then the data to the server will be send only if the user type <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Sorry, but your second question "we need to arrange the dataset (json) according to the parameters user sent from the backend and will it be rendered as it is in the jqgrid" I don't understand. Probably [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819) will help you. If you mean something other, please describe your requirement more exactly in another words.

I don't know and don't use spring mvc, but I have seen some tutorials on the http://krams915.blogspot.com site: for example [this one](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/jqgrid-and-spring-3-mvc-integration.html). It seems to me that in the examples which you can download will be used [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching), so it could bring you forward.

Comment: Thank you very much oleg. i looked in to that example, but filterToolbar is not functional in that. i will do more workaround and will post my observations. Appreciate your help.